# How to add scrollbar and styling only if content overflows element?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML document with a `<nav>` element used for navigation buttons. The number of buttons is variable but the width of the `<nav>` element is fixed. I want to have an `overflow-x: scroll;` to be active only if the content overflows and add some extra rules to make the scrollbar "pretty" and fit into the look of the page.

Can this be done using CSS or JS? (Strong preference for CSS only)

Comment: Did you try `overflow-x: auto;`?

Comment: @FluffyKitten He also wants to add style. Tho I think it's not possible with pure css.

Comment: @Cons7an7ine Yes I know. That's why I only added it in a comment instead of adding an answer.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: Yes, but triggering styling is what I can't figure out as Cons7an7ine suggested.

Comment: As I already said, I know there's more to your question, which is why I posted a comment instead of a full answer. If I had the *full* answer, I'd have posted it.

Comment: There is no cross-browser custom scrollbar styling via css. You must need takes help from useful plugins like this: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: @Hanif No, but I can theme the elements around it to make it blend in and look part of the design.